# how can i change the password length in create user wizard of visual studo in asp.net

Tags: asp.net

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true"  CodeFile="Default.aspx.cs" Inherits="_Default" %>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" >
<head runat="server">
    <title>Untitled Page</title>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div style="text-align: center">
        <asp:CreateUserWizard ID="CreateUserWizard1" runat="server" OnCreatedUser="CreateUserWizard1_CreatedUser">
            <WizardSteps>
                <asp:CreateUserWizardStep runat="server">
                </asp:CreateUserWizardStep>
                <asp:CompleteWizardStep runat="server">
                </asp:CompleteWizardStep>
            </WizardSteps>
        </asp:CreateUserWizard>

    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

In your web.config is a section to configure the Membership. You can change the minimum password-length here:

example:

```
<membership defaultProvider="MySqlMembershipProvider">
  <providers>
    <add name="MySqlMembershipProvider" 
         connectionStringName="MyLocalSQLServer" 
         applicationName="MyAppName"
         minRequiredPasswordLength="8"
         minRequiredNonalphanumericCharacters="2"
         type="System.Web.Security.SqlMembershipProvider, System.Web, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a"/>
  </providers>
</membership>
```